# Using Apache HttpClient with Twitter Streaming API response issues

Tags: java, twitter, streaming, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

So I decided to give the Twitter Streaming api a shot so I went up to the twitter dev page and created a test application generated my oAuth tokens and all then I tried it using the curl command in the terminal and I got the stream coming in just fine, but then I decided to try to write a little piece of java snippet to sort of do the same thing then its where I faced the problem.

Below here is my code, I have removed my tokens and authorization codes by writing in * instead of the real ones.

```
public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json");
        final String header = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"********\", oauth_nonce=\"*******", oauth_signature=\"**************", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1339160825\", oauth_token=\"*********", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
        final String headerTitle = "Authorization";
        post.addHeader(headerTitle, header);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(post, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        System.out.println("Reponse status code: " + e.getStatusCode()
                + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

I have also removed the import lines.

I keep getting a 401 response, might be something that I'm doing wrong with the headers.

Thank you in advance.